# How to delete contains of a folder with out deleting the folder remotely..?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file

I don't have `AD` access, but i have `C$` access.
There is folder name icon in every profile n almost every system in the domain.
I like to delete it.
THIS IS THE PATH

```
\\%PCNAME%\c$\TSAPL\Users\%id%\Apps\icons
```

for

`/f %%a in (C:\pclist1.txt) do for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /ad /a-h /b \\%%a\c$\Users\') do if exist "\\%%a\c$\Users\%%b\Apps\icons" rd /s /q \\%%a\c$\TSAPL\Users\%%b\Apps\icons`

THIS WILL DELETE THE FOLDER.
BUT I DON'T WANT THE FOLDER TO GET DELETED.

PLS HELP.

Answer (score 3):

rd is remove Directory (folder).

Change the delete command to:

```
del \\%%a\c$\TSAPL\Users\%%b\Apps\icons\*
```

That will delete all files with in the icons directory but leave the parent folder intact.